Airbyte Campaign missing in Data
in Airbyte i have setup a source from Google Ads. The Client ID, Secret, Refresh Token is filled in. Then i input the CUSTOMER ID. Under this customer there are several Campaigns, but one Active one is missing in the final data that i receive from Airbyte.
Should i refresh the Client ID/Secret/Token or do i need to enable this missing Campaign in Google Ads?
I would assume that all campaigns should be automatically included if they are under the common Customer ID.
Thank you
